# Using injection in JAXB XmlAdapters for Spring RESTful Controller

Tags: xml, spring, rest, jaxb

My application requires instances of the `JAXB XmlAdapter` such as

```
public class CategoryTypeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Category> {

    @Autowired
    protected CategoryService categoryService;

    public CategoryTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Category v) throws Exception {
        return (v == null) ? null : v.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Category unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // noop
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(v)) {
            return null;
        }
        // load via service
        return this.categoryService.getCategory(v);
    }
}
```

Question: How can I configure Spring's `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` to set this adapter in the appropriate mashaller?

I know there is the Spring OXM library but I am not clear on how I can use the OXM classes together with my annotation driven REST controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot associate an XmlAdapter to Spring's message converters, instead use the normal JAXB mechanism to register this XmlAdapter with the type where you require it:

```
public class MyRootElement{

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CategoryTypeAdapter.class)
   private Category category;

}
```

Now the question of how to inject in a `CategoryService` into `CategoryTypeAdapter`, there are a couple of ways to inject in a Spring dependency into a non Spring managed object, probably the simplest if you have AspectJ infrastructure will be to use `@Configurable` annotation on your Adapter.

Comment: Cheers, will give that a try. I have already changed my adapter to simply return an empty Category instance with just the id set in case the categoryservice is null. After parsing I replace those dummy category instances with the real mckoy